# Listview Not binding through ViewModel

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I am getting a problem while I am binding the `ListView` with a `ViewModel`. I have created an object of `ViewModel` class and set it as BindingContext of `ListView`. This object contains 4 items when it gets initialised but the `ListView` remains blank. I am not sure what I am missing here. I have added the code below -

```
public class LeadershipViewModel
{
    private PfsServiceArea _oldProduct;
    public ObservableCollection Products { get; set; }
    public LeadershipViewModel()
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection();
        var PFSArea = new PfsServices().GetPFSServiceArea("Leadership");
        if (PFSArea.Count > 0){
            foreach(PfsServiceArea pf in PFSArea){
            Products.Add(pf);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowOrHidePoducts(PfsServiceArea product)
    {
        if (_oldProduct == product)
        {
            // click twice on the same item will hide it
            product.ShowDescription = false;
            product.ShowDisplay = true;
            UpdateProducts(product);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_oldProduct != null)
            {
                // hide previous selected item
                product.ShowDescription = true;
                product.ShowDisplay = false;
                UpdateProducts(_oldProduct);
            }
            // show selected item
            product.ShowDescription = true;
            product.ShowDisplay = false;
            UpdateProducts(product);
        }

        _oldProduct = product;
    }

    private void UpdateProducts(PfsServiceArea product)
    {
        var index = Products.IndexOf(product);
        Products.Remove(product);
        Products.Insert(index, product);
    }
```

And I have binded it with `ListView` like below -

```
Private LeadershipViewModel leader = new LeadershipViewModel();
sicCodeList = new CustomListview(ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement)
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
    ItemTemplate = sicDataTemplate,
    SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None,
    Margin = new Thickness(-5, 0, 0, 0),
    BindingContext = leader
};
sicCodeList.HasUnevenRows = true;
//sicCodeList.BindingContext = leader;
sicCodeList.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Products");
sicCodeList.ItemTapped += (sender, e) => OnItemTapped(sender, e);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to set the BindingContext of the page to your ViewModel. Then, you can bind the list to your listview's ItemsSource:

```
private LeadershipViewModel leader = new LeadershipViewModel();

public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = leader;
    ListView sicCodeList = new ListView() { ... set properties ... };
    sicCodeList.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Products");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to set `ItemSource` property for your `ListView`

```
sicCodeList.ItemSource = leader.Products;
```

more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/get-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms#Lists_in_Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: Thanks I got it working. Though there is one more things now. OnItemTapped I am not able to get the BindingContext, because of which I am not able to hit the method ShowOrHidePoducts under ViewModel. Below is the code where vm is always NULL -         
 private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var product = e.Item as PfsServiceArea;
            var vm = BindingContext as LeadershipViewModel;
            vm.ShowOrHidePoducts(product);
            ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; 
        }

Comment: Why you are not directly calling it with vm instance like `leader.ShowOrHidePoducts(product);` in your `onItemTapped` method